# How to generate a CSV file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, export

I have data exported to excel it works fine.
But I have a little question

My output is exported like this:

[image]

What i would like to happen is this:

[image]

and this is my code to export:

```
-(void)exportCSV {

    NSArray * data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:entries,keys, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
    csv =[NSMutableString string];
    for (NSArray * line in data) {
        NSMutableArray * formattedLine = [NSMutableArray array];
        for ( field in line) {
            BOOL shouldQuote = NO;
            NSRange r = [field rangeOfString:@","];
            //fields that contain a , must be quoted
            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                shouldQuote = YES;
            }
            r = [field rangeOfString:@"\""];
            //fields that contain a " must have them escaped to "" and be quoted
            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                field = [field stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
                shouldQuote = YES;
            }
            if (shouldQuote == YES) {
                [formattedLine addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"\"%@\"", entries,keys]];
            } else {
                [formattedLine addObject:field];
            }
        }

        NSString * combinedLine = [formattedLine componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
        [csv appendFormat:@"%@\n", combinedLine];

        NSLog(@"%@",csv);
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like your first line in `data` is the column headers, and subsequent lines contain the data. Since you are processing things one line at a time, you get what you expect. To get the transpose, you need to read all the data into the columns of an array, then read it out in rows (or vice versa). Or, after opening the Excel file for the first time, do a "select all - cut - paste special - transpose". The latter would be easier...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Excel. This is a "generating CSV" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following do what you want?
*Note that I have not considered quotation, I leave that up to you ;)*
*Also note that I assume that entries.count == keys.count*

```
- (void)exportCSV {    
    NSArray *keys = @[@"T", @"R", @"RTT"];
    NSArray *entries = @[@"-329180696", @"1243918297", @"-998693494"];
    NSMutableString *csv = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.count; i++) {
        [csv appendFormat:@"%@;%@\n", keys[i], entries[i]];
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> T;-329180696
>   R;1243918297
>   RTT;-998693494

Comment: If I wan to pass T;-321455,5565656,4555 then how can I do it, I passed array for first key but it is showing bracket in csv T;(
    one,
    two,
    three
)
R;1243918297
RTT;-998693494

Comment: The `()` are there because it's the description method implementation of `NSArray`. Can you please show me how you changed the code in my answer and how your data structure looks like? (where is the `4555` coming from?

Comment: NSArray *keys = @[@"T", @"R", @"RTT"];
NSArray *oneArr = @[@"one",@"two",@"three"];
NSString* alertString = [oneArr componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSArray *entries = @[alertString, @"1243918297", @"-998693494"];
NSMutableString *csv = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (int i = 0; i < entries.count; i++) {
[csv appendFormat:@"%@;%@\n", keys[i], entries[i]];
}
NSLog(@"csv %@",csv);

Comment: I want to pass no. of rows for one key.